# tcpdump with -w -C -G and -z options

Tags: gzip, pcap, tcpdump

I'm trying to take continuous traces which are written to files that are limited by both duration (-G option) and size (-C option).  The files are automatically named with the -w option, and finally the files are compressed with the -z gzip option.  Altogether what I have is:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -w /home/me/pcaps/MyTrace_%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.pcap -s 0 -C 100 -G 3600 -Z root -z gzip &
```

The problem is that with the -C option, the current file count is appended onto the name, so I wind up with files ending in: `.pcap2.gz .pcap3.gz .pcap4.gz`, etc.  I would much prefer to have them end as: `_2.pcap.gz _3.pcap.gz _4.pcap.gz, etc.`

But if I remove .pcap from the -w option, I wind up with `2.gz 3.gz 4.gz`

This could work if I could include options in the "-z" command like `-z "gzip -S .pcap.gz"` so that gzip itself appends the .pcap or if I could use an alias like `pcap_gzip="gzip -S .pcap.gz"` and then `-z pcap_gzip`, but neither option seems to be working, the latter producing this error: `compress_savefile:execlp(gzip -S pcap.gz, /home/me/pcaps/MyTrace_2018-08-07_105308_27): No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem today, In CentOS6. I found your problem, but the answer did not work to me.
In fact, it only needs to be adjusted slightly, that is, the absolute path of the saved file name and the name of the script to be executed is written, for example

```
tcpdump -i em1 ... -s 0 -G 10 -w '/home/Svr01_std_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.pcap' -Z root -z /home/pcapup2arcive.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that although the alias doesn't work, I was able to put the same commands in a script and invoke the script via `tcpdump -z`.

pcap_gzip.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
gzip -S .pcap.gz "$@"
```

Then:
`tcpdump -i eth0 -w /home/me/pcaps/MyTrace_%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S -s 0 -C 100 -G 3600 -Z root -z pcap_gzip.sh &`